# How to get Lambda's response from React Axios

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, axios, amazon-dynamodb

I have the app setup like below and I want to get the Lambda's response through API to show the item list in web.

**User <-> API Gateway <-> Lambda <-> DynamoDB**

Below is the example of code I'm using.

```
// React component
async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const res = await axios.post('https://***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/functionName', {})
    console.log(res)
}

// It returns "null" and nothing in Payload.
```

```
// Lambda Function
client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
data = client.scan(TableName='myTable');
response = {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps(data),
    'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
}
return response;


// Lambda Function Test response is;
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"Items\": [{\"date\": {\"N\": \"123\"}, \"message\": {\"S\": \"msg\"}}....], \"Count\": .....",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
}
```

In Lambda, I can get the list of DynamoDB items in JSON format without issue. Do you have any idea why I get "Null" in React? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was from my API Gateway setup.
I created an HTTP API, set Route with GET method with Lambda function integration. It works!